# GTK and home-brew

Tags: macos, gtk, homebrew

Crew, I am trying to compile a simple program using GTK4 in OSX. I developed stuff in Intel Mac before using GTK, python and C and now I am trying to take to everything to the new osx. I installed home-brew which now installs in a different directory in arm64.

```
/opt/homebrew
```

Instead of the one used in Intel Macs:

```
/usr/local
```

Then I used the command:

```
vi ~/. zshrc
```

To add the next lines to my file:

```
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
export HOMEBREW_PREFIX="/opt/homebrew";
export HOMEBREW_CELLAR="/opt/homebrew/Cellar";
export HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY="/opt/homebrew";
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin${PATH+:$PATH}";
export MANPATH="/opt/homebrew/share/man${MANPATH+:$MANPATH}:";
export INFOPATH="/opt/homebrew/share/info:${INFOPATH:-}";
```

The next lines also exist:

```
alias python=/usr/bin/python3
alias python=/opt/homebrew/bin/python3.10
```

The last ones allow me to run Python which I installed using Brew. But when I try to run my gtk code with C I get the next error:

```
fatal error: 'gtk/gtk.h' file not found
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
```

As far as I know the problem is "I can't find the libraries you are asking for". So there is something broken somewhere.

I did a little trick, I tried to help my compiler by setting the address of my library in the sample code as:

```
#include </opt/homebrew/Cellar/gtk4/4.12.0/include/gtk-4.0/gtk/gtk.h>
```

Just to see what happens. And as I was expecting, the compiler found gtk.h but gave me the next error:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gtk4/4.12.0/include/gtk-4.0/gtk/gtk.h:29:10: fatal error: 
'gtk/css/gtkcss.h' file not found
#include <gtk/css/gtkcss.h>
```

So basically it says "I can't find the library!", but when I search for the library that library is in the path:

```
/gtk/css
```

Again, something is broken and I am lacking a link to tell my zsh where are my libraries but I assume already did that by including the text lines o shown to your crew. Do you have any idea about this?. I think I am on the right path so far!.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed, OMG I just had to install pkg-config. I feel so dumb, all those steps do not work If I don't do:

```
brew install pkg-config
```

Then using the command:

```
gcc hellow.c -o helloworld `pkg-config gtk4 --cflags pkg-config gtk4 --libs`
```

Works as a charm to run the GTK+C code... here we goooooo!!!!.

Comment: working answer even for m1 pro, thank you! seems to be no upto date instructions